# CSS selector for text within <dt> element (definition list tag)

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Seemingly straightforward question, but I'm unable to find any documentation to clarify what the correct approach is.

Given a set of description tags (dt elements) as below, how can I get the text from one of the elements using a CSS selector (when looping over the `<div>` elements)?

```
<div class="data">
    <dt class="title">Date</dt>
    <dd class="info">14/09/2018</dd>
</div>
<div class="data">
    <dt class="title">Time</dt>
    <dd class="info">14:55</dd>
</div>
```

For example, how can I get the word "Date" from the first `<dt>`?

I have tried what appears to be the normal css selector approach that I would use for a `<div>` or similar, as below:

```
dt.title ::text
```

but this does not return the text, and produces no result. Is there another way to get this text with a css selector?

If I use the selector `dt.title` only, I get the full tag (i.e. not just the text) so I'm confident that part works, but I must be missing something in the second parameter.

Comment: What do you mean by "get the text"? You used it twice but I don't understand what you're trying to do. You tagged your question with jQuery, so are you trying to get the text of that node? Have you tried `.text()` or `.html()`?

Comment: CSS selectors are just used to match the element, so that you can apply a style to it. They don't return information about the element.

Comment: Sorry, the jquery tag appears to have been added in error (must have clicked on a suggestion) - I am trying to do this with css only.

Comment: by "get the text" I mean I'm looking for a selector that will return only the text bounded by the tag, rather than the full tag itself. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @HO that's impossible to do with `css` only, so you might as well add that `jquery` tag back :P https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520429/is-there-a-css-selector-for-elements-containing-certain-text

Comment: As Barmar said, you can't return anything with CSS. It selects elements so you can style them.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, understood that this isn't possible. I'll try getting the full element and parsing it.

Comment: @HO why would you parse the full element if my answer will get you the text?

Comment: @SergChernata I don't have access to jQuery in this application - the jQuery tag was added in error.

Comment: With plain javascript, use `document.querySelector('dt.title').textContent` to get the text. It will find the first occurrence. If to find all, as a node list, use `querySelectorAll` and then iterate the result and get each text with `textContent`

Comment: H O, your example of ::text suggests this is a web scraping library (like Scrapy, where that specific selector appears). Are you using one? If so, what you're doing is very possible, with Scrapy (in fact the selector you have should work), or by selecting the dt and extracting its text using just about any other web scraper. The term "CSS" (as well as the use of the [css] tag) may be confusing everyone here because CSS selectors are often referred to using the term "CSS", although that's by no means your fault. This confusion happens regularly here.

Answer (score 4):

[There is no such `css` pseudo selector.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes#Index_of_standard_pseudo-classes) What you're looking for is:

```
$('dt.title').text();
```

Or vanilla `javascript`:

```
document.querySelector('dt.title').textContent;
```